# Vuex Action - Returning Axios return Error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, vuejs2, vuex

Vuex Action - Returning Axios return Error.

What am I doing wrong that the promise is not returning the correct values?

Someone could help with this doubt.

I want to display the error message behind the server.

From now on I am very grateful for the attention.
Thank you.

Component

```
<q-form
                @submit="onSubmit"
                @reset="onReset"
              >
                <q-input outlined v-model="username" label="User" />
                <br>
                <q-input outlined v-model="password" type="password" label="Pass" />
                <br>
                <q-btn unelevated  type="submit" color="primary full-width" label="Enter" />
              </q-form>
```

---

```
    methods: {
...mapActions('auth', ['login']),
onSubmit () {
          this.login({ 'username': this.username, 'password': this.password }).then(obj => {
            console.log(obj)
          }).catch(obj => {
            console.log(obj)
          })
        }
}
```

---

```
function login ({ commit, state, getters }, data) {
  return axios.post(`/api/token`, {
    username: data.username,
    password: data.password
  })
    .then(response => {
      commit('setToken', response.data)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      return error
    })
}
```

> POST http://localhost/api/token 400 (Bad Request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your function instead of pasting it directly into the methods object:

```
methods: {
  ...mapActions('auth', ['login']),
  myLogin() {
    this.login({ 'username': this.username, 'password': this.password }).then(obj => {
      console.log(obj)
    }).catch(obj => {
      this.error = obj;
    })
  },
}
```

Also, you are mapping an action of the same name: `login`, so you would need to change your local method to a different name, which is why I called it `myLogin`.

Create a `data` property called `error` and use:  `{{ error }}` in your component where you intend to show the error.

Comment: I did an issue in more detail. Thank you guys

Comment: Good, please also show the `export` in the `auth` module.

Comment: export {
  login
}

Comment: Now I see you are getting a 400 error, so the request is probably being sent just fine, but you are sending the wrong information.  Have you verified the values of `this.username` and `this.password`?

Comment: That's just it. The 400 error comes with a message from the server. So I intend to display this message.

Comment: password: ["This field can not be null."]
0: "This field can not be null."
username: ["This field can not be null."]
0: "This field can not be null."

Comment: I see.  Can you not call a separate method instead, where you log to the console, which stores the error in a component property?  Then show that property in your template somewhere?  I updated my answer.

Comment: I understand. OK then. Thanks for listening.

Comment: You're quite welcome.  Feel free to upvote/accept if my answer helped you.